# PID: 18319 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to use Spoonacular API in Android using Jetpack Compose and Kotlin

but I got an error

> BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

and I can't figure out how to solve this problem

Here is my JSON Format

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "vegetarian": true,
      "vegan": true,
      "glutenFree": true,
      "dairyFree": true,
      "veryHealthy": false,
      "cheap": false,
      "veryPopular": false,
      "sustainable": false,
      "lowFodmap": false,
      "weightWatcherSmartPoints": 0,
      "gaps": "GAPS_FULL",
      "preparationMinutes": -1,
      "cookingMinutes": -1,
      "aggregateLikes": 1,
      "healthScore": 51,
      "creditsText": "Foodista.com – The Cooking Encyclopedia Everyone Can Edit",
      "license": "CC BY 3.0",
      "sourceName": "Foodista",
      "pricePerServing": 81.7,
      "extendedIngredients": [
        {
          "id": 11080,
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "image": "beets.jpg",
          "consistency": "SOLID",
          "name": "beet",
          "nameClean": "red beet",
          "original": "1 Beet, peeled",
          "originalName": "Beet, peeled",
          "amount": 1.0,
          "unit": "",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "measures": {
            "us": {
              "amount": 1.0,
              "unitShort": "",
              "unitLong": ""
            },
            "metric": {
              "amount": 1.0,
              "unitShort": "",
              "unitLong": ""
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 11124,
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "image": "sliced-carrot.png",
          "consistency": "SOLID",
          "name": "carrots",
          "nameClean": "carrot",
          "original": "1 pound Carrots, peeled",
          "originalName": "Carrots, peeled",
          "amount": 1.0,
          "unit": "pound",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "measures": {
            "us": {
              "amount": 1.0,
              "unitShort": "lb",
              "unitLong": "pound"
            },
            "metric": {
              "amount": 453.592,
              "unitShort": "g",
              "unitLong": "grams"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 9200,
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "image": "orange.png",
          "consistency": "SOLID",
          "name": "oranges",
          "nameClean": "orange",
          "original": "2 pounds Oranges, peeled",
          "originalName": "Oranges, peeled",
          "amount": 2.0,
          "unit": "pounds",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "measures": {
            "us": {
              "amount": 2.0,
              "unitShort": "lb",
              "unitLong": "pounds"
            },
            "metric": {
              "amount": 907.185,
              "unitShort": "g",
              "unitLong": "grams"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": 1095729,
      "title": "Immunity Booster Beet, Carrot & Orange Juice",
      "readyInMinutes": 10,
      "servings": 4,
      "sourceUrl": "https://www.foodista.com/recipe/HHM34WCD/immune-booster-beet-carrot-orange-juice",
      "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/1095729-312x231.jpg",
      "imageType": "jpg",
      "summary": "Need a <b>gluten free, dairy free, paleolithic, and lacto ovo vegetarian beverage</b>? Immunity Booster Beet, Carrot & Orange Juice could be an outstanding recipe to try. This recipe makes 4 servings with <b>162 calories</b>, <b>4g of protein</b>, and <b>1g of fat</b> each. For <b>82 cents per serving</b>, this recipe <b>covers 18%</b> of your daily requirements of vitamins and minerals. This recipe from Foodista has 1 fans. If you have beet, carrots, oranges, and a few other ingredients on hand, you can make it. From preparation to the plate, this recipe takes roughly <b>10 minutes</b>. Overall, this recipe earns an <b>amazing spoonacular score of 89%</b>. If you like this recipe, you might also like recipes such as <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/goji-orange-turmeric-smoothie-the-immunity-booster-610828\">Goji-Orange-Turmeric Smoothie (“The Immunity Booster”)</a>, <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/rejuvenating-root-juice-carrot-beet-blood-orange-ginger-turmeric-juice-1226953\">Rejuvenating Root Juice | Carrot, Beet, Blood Orange, Ginger, Turmeric Juice</a>, and <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/rejuvenating-root-juice-carrot-beet-blood-orange-ginger-turmeric-juice-1238761\">Rejuvenating Root Juice | Carrot, Beet, Blood Orange, Ginger, Turmeric Juice</a>.",
      "cuisines": [
        
      ],
      "dishTypes": [
        "beverage",
        "drink"
      ],
      "diets": [
        "gluten free",
        "dairy free",
        "paleolithic",
        "lacto ovo vegetarian",
        "primal",
        "whole 30",
        "vegan"
      ],
      "occasions": [
        
      ],
      "analyzedInstructions": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "steps": [
            {
              "number": 1,
              "step": "Roughly chop the beet, carrots and oranges. When peeling and chopping the beet, use gloves and apron to avoid staining your hands and clothes.Throw them in a juicer and in about 2 minutes you will end up with this delicious healthy juice.",
              "ingredients": [
                {
                  "id": 11124,
                  "name": "carrot",
                  "localizedName": "carrot",
                  "image": "sliced-carrot.png"
                },
                {
                  "id": 9200,
                  "name": "orange",
                  "localizedName": "orange",
                  "image": "orange.png"
                },
                {
                  "id": 1019016,
                  "name": "juice",
                  "localizedName": "juice",
                  "image": "apple-juice.jpg"
                },
                {
                  "id": 11080,
                  "name": "beet",
                  "localizedName": "beet",
                  "image": "beets.jpg"
                }
              ],
              "equipment": [
                {
                  "id": 404683,
                  "name": "juicer",
                  "localizedName": "juicer",
                  "image": "juicer.jpg"
                }
              ],
              "length": {
                "number": 2,
                "unit": "minutes"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "spoonacularSourceUrl": "https://spoonacular.com/immunity-booster-beet-carrot-orange-juice-1095729",
      "usedIngredientCount": 0,
      "missedIngredientCount": 3,
      "missedIngredients": [
        {
          "id": 11080,
          "amount": 1.0,
          "unit": "",
          "unitLong": "",
          "unitShort": "",
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "name": "beet",
          "original": "1 Beet, peeled",
          "originalName": "Beet, peeled",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "image": "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/beets.jpg"
        },
        {
          "id": 11124,
          "amount": 1.0,
          "unit": "pound",
          "unitLong": "pound",
          "unitShort": "lb",
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "name": "carrots",
          "original": "1 pound Carrots, peeled",
          "originalName": "Carrots, peeled",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "image": "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/sliced-carrot.png"
        },
        {
          "id": 9200,
          "amount": 2.0,
          "unit": "pounds",
          "unitLong": "pounds",
          "unitShort": "lb",
          "aisle": "Produce",
          "name": "oranges",
          "original": "2 pounds Oranges, peeled",
          "originalName": "Oranges, peeled",
          "meta": [
            "peeled"
          ],
          "image": "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/orange.png"
        }
      ],
      "likes": 0,
      "usedIngredients": [
        
      ],
      "unusedIngredients": [
        
      ]
    }
  ],
  "offset": 0,
  "number": 1,
  "totalResults": 40
}
```

**Model**

```
data class ResultX(
    @SerializedName("aggregateLikes")
    val aggregateLikes: Int,
    @SerializedName("cheap")
    val cheap: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("dairyFree")
    val dairyFree: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("extendedIngredients")
    val extendedIngredients: List<ExtendedIngredient>,
    @SerializedName("glutenFree")
    val glutenFree: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("likes")
    val likes: Int,
    @SerializedName("readyInMinutes")
    val readyInMinutes: Int,
    @SerializedName("servings")
    val servings: Int,
    @SerializedName("sourceName")
    val sourceName: String,
    @SerializedName("sourceUrl")
    val sourceUrl: String,
    @SerializedName("summary")
    val summary: String,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String,
    @SerializedName("vegan")
    val vegan: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("vegetarian")
    val vegetarian: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("veryHealthy")
    val veryHealthy: Boolean
)

data class ExtendedIngredient(
    @SerializedName("amount")
    val amount: Double,
    @SerializedName("consistency")
    val consistency: String,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("original")
    val original: String,
    @SerializedName("unit")
    val unit: String
)
```

***API INTERFACE***

```
  @GET("/recipes/complexSearch")
    suspend fun getRecipes(
        @QueryMap queries: Map<String, String>
    ): List<ResultX>
```

***RESOURCE CLASS AND API REPOSITORY IMPLEMENTATION***

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null){
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String?, data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data)
}

interface FoodApiRepository {
    fun getRecipes(queries: Map<String, String>): Flow<Resource<List<ResultX>>>
}

class FoodApiRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val foodApi: FoodApi
): FoodApiRepository {

    override fun getRecipes(queries: Map<String, String>): Flow<Resource<List<ResultX>>> {
        return flow {
            try {
                emit(Resource.Loading())
                val result = foodApi.getRecipes(queries = queries)
                emit(
                    Resource.Success(
                        data = result
                    )
                )
            }catch (e: HttpException){
                emit(Resource.Error(e.localizedMessage ?: "An expected error occurred"))
            }catch (e: IOException){
                emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't reach server. Check your internet connection"))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**FOOD LIST STATE CLASS AND HOME VIEW MODEL**

```
data class FoodListState(
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val recipes: List<ResultX> = emptyList(),
    val error: String = ""
)

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val foodApiRepository: FoodApiRepository
): ViewModel(){

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(FoodListState())
    val state: State<FoodListState> = _state

    init {
        getRecipes(applyQueries())
    }

    private fun getRecipes(queries: Map<String, String>) {
        foodApiRepository.getRecipes(queries = queries).onEach { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = FoodListState(recipes = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state.value =
                        FoodListState(
                            error = result.message ?: "An un expected error occurred"
                        )
                    Log.d("TAG", "getFoodRecipes: ERROR")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = FoodListState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    private fun applyQueries(): HashMap<String, String> {
        val queries: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

        queries["number"] = "50"
        queries["apiKey"] = API_KEY
        queries["type"] = "snack"
        queries["diet"] = "vegan"
        queries["addRecipeInformation"] = "true"
        queries["fillIngredients"] = "true"

        Log.d("TAG", "applyQueries: $queries")

        return queries
    }

}
```

***HOME SCREEN***

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = homeViewModel.state.value

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(state.recipes) { recipe ->
                Text(
                    text = recipe.title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(20.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        if (state.error.isNotBlank()){
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(
                        Alignment.Center
                    )
            )
        }
        if (state.isLoading){
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

***THANK YOU***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're parsing it wrong.  Your Retrofit function says it returns a List.  That's not what the JSON being returned is.  It's returning a JSON object, not a JSON Array.  You need another class ResultWrapper which has a a list of ResultX in it named result, and have the Retrofit API return that.

Comment: thank you so much! I managed to solve my problem

`
data class ResultWrapper(
    @SerializedName("results")
    val result: List<ResultX>
)
`

I just need to clarify things, all I need to do is **change my return type from List to a new class (ResultWrapper)** in retrofit function also my repositories need to change from **Flow<Resource<List<ResultX>>>** to **Flow<Resource<ResultWrapper>>>**
am I right?